# Using '.splice()' in React Native to Add to an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native

I'm trying to use `.splice()` to and an object to an array in the state function. The code I have is from a score keeper app that compiles.

```
    state = {
         team1: 'Team 1',
         team2: 'Team 2',
         score1: 0,
         score2: 0,
         team1Stats: [0, 0, 0],
         team2Stats: [0, 0, 0],
         date: 'Enter Date Here',
         gameRecord: [
             ],
    }

    updateRanking = () => {
         this.state.gameRecord.splice(this.state.gameRecord.length, 0, {
         finalDate: this.state.date,
         team1FinalScore: this.state.score1,
         team2FinalScore: this.state.score2,
    })
```

When I run the code, the app runs however when I make a call to `.updateRanking()` I get an error that reads:

> Error Invariant Violation: Minified React error #31

What do I have to change?

Comment: `gameRecord` is empty array and you are applying splice on it so that wouldn't work

Comment: @NooruddinLakhani do I have to add an object in the array within state first for the error to go away, and if so what is the syntax for that

Comment: It's working fine you check https://codesandbox.io/s/q4qymyp2l6?file=/src/App.js:3240-3246